# POST request returns 415 - Unsupported Media Type

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-services, jersey, http-status-code-415

Even if this error is known, I was not able to solve my issue!

The reset Service is declared in this code :

```
 @POST
    @Transactional
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/addProduct")
    public void addProductToShoppingBag(JSONObject object) throws JSONException
```

and I'm sending a POST request using this javascript :

```
$.ajax({
            header: 'application/json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $.toJSON({
            member_id: "1",
            products_id: ["0","1"]
        }),
            url: url
        }).done(success).error(failure);
```

and I'm getting the 415 - Unsupported Media Type error !!! any idea ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to set `contentType`.  Your header is not formatted properly

Switch:

```
 header: 'application/json',
```

To

```
contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
```

The proper header needs to include  `'Content-Type'` in it and jQuery will take care of that for you